# HTML - How can I store my custom radio button into my localStorage?

Tags: html, css, input, radio-button, label

Okay, so I got a custom radio button:

```
              <label class="radiobtn" id="region">EUW
                <input type="radio" name="radio">
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
              </label>
```

And I'd like to store the text next to it (EUW) into a localStorage item called "region", when the radio button is checked.
There are multiple radio buttons of this and i want to do it for all of them.
Each custom radio button has another value (EUW, EUNE, JP, KR, etc...)
Everything else is similar.
So I kinda tried to figure out how I could do that, but I couldn't came across a good solution.

Do you guys have some good solutions? :O
Thank you for any help, I appreciate it.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You create custom radio buttons all with same class radiobtn, then in JQuery on radiobtn class click event check if radio button is checked, get label text and store it in localStorage.

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/mLst49h8/

**HTML**

```
<label class="radiobtn" >EUW
  <input type="radio" name="radio" >
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="radiobtn" >EUNE
  <input type="radio" name="radio" >
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

**JQuery**

```
$( ".radiobtn" ).click(function() {
  if($(this).children("input").is(":checked"))   {
      // alert( $(this).text());
      var region = $(this).text();
      localStorage.setItem("region", region);
      region = localStorage.getItem("region");
      alert(region);
   }
});
```